# How to slide a activity in android

Tags: android

how to Slide an activity like the image below, after sliding the trail of the activities must be visible like the below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoXy7.png)

Comment: Thats not activity, thats clearly fragments with viewpager.

Comment: You can use ViewPager with fragments for that

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library [DiscreteScrollView](https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView) just you need to customize the adapter layout as your requirement.

Comment: I am not sure if you have ever heard of ViewPager or RecyclerView at least?

Comment: just before saying that just go through that library

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, and thats why I mentioned that, its simply recycler view with additional changes. Same can be done with viewpager without additional dependency on external library.

Comment: i am not saying that it cannot be done just try using this approach as you'll get what you want with little efforts